# Make form checkboxes appear in the email sent from the form

Tags: php, forms, email, checkbox

I'm quite new too PHP and I'm trying to make a contact from containing a name text box, an email box some checkboxes and a comment section.

I have made everything work except the checkboxes, as you can see from the script below, it will send the information to my email, however I don't understand how to make the checkboxes appear in the email.

In other words, it will not tell me what boxes have been checked in the email. Any simple solution to this?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Website'; 
$to = 'example@mail.com'; 
$subject = 'Order';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Packages: $cbox\n Message: $message";
?>


<label><strong>Name</strong></label>
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Type Here">

<label><strong>Email</strong></label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

<label><strong>Packages</strong></label>    
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="Logo">Logo</input>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="Website">Website+Domain</input>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="cbox" value="Other">Other</input>

<label><strong>Message</strong></label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
 if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
 } else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see a problem in that. If you want to prevent warnings you should put the part:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Website'; 
$to = 'example@mail.com'; 
$subject = 'Order';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Packages: $cbox\n Message: $message";
```

under the `if ($_POST['submit']) {`

also i miss some `<form action="yourfile.php" method="post">`

didn't see theres also no `$name = $_POST['cbox'];`

But if you do that way you will only see the last element checked, you would need to give the checkboxes different names to get all values